# WPF add Paragraph into TableCell by code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How I can add two `Paragraph` in to `TableCell` by code? In XAML it's looks like

```
<TableCell>
    <Paragraph>first</Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>second</Paragraph>
</TableCell>
```

In code I can do like this

```
TableCell firstCell = new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run("first")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding to the **Blocks** of the TableCell

Take a look at MSDN [TableCell.Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.tablecell.blocks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Ideally it would look something like this

```
//I did not test this code
TableCell firstCell = new TableCell();
firstCell.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("first")));
```

Hope that was helpful!

Comment: Thanks! Working properly.